# How to import (mysql-connector-2.2.9) module package from local directory in python script

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x

I have used mysql connector using this mysql-connector-2.2.9 module in of my script. now i need to execute the script in user system without installing module.user has installed only python.i have downloaded this package and stored locally but not able to import the module using `sys.path.append` this function. i am getting an error like NO module installed.

```
import sys
sys.path.append("C:/newfolder/mysql-connector-2.2.9")
from mysql-connector-2.2.9 import mysql.connector
```

i want to know how import this package locally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried this and it worked for me...

```
    from pathlib import Path
    import sys

    path_root = Path('C:/newfolder/mysql-connector-2.2.9').parents[2]
    sys.path.append(str(path_root))
            
    from mysql-connector-2.2.9 import mysql.connector
```

But you will have to put the path in.
I used this page https://fortierq.github.io/python-import/
If the code doesn't help, maybe you can find something here.